# why my code throwing error??? whether any xslt class files to be downloaded, if so where can I get the class files

Tags: java, eclipse, xslt

```
XSLTProcessor processor ;
    
    String xslfilename="file:///"+Environment.getProperty(com.xxxxxxxx.Constants.EDUJINI_CONST_CONTEXT);
    String xmlfilename="file:///"+Environment.getProperty(com.xxxxxxxx.Constants.EDUJINI_CONST_CONTEXT);
    xslfilename += sep+"administration/desktopadmin_top.xsl";
    xmlfilename += sep+"administration/portaladmin_top.xml";
    try{
        processor= XSLTProcessorFactory.getProcessor();
        XSLTInputSource inputxml=new XSLTInputSource(xmlfilename);
        XSLTInputSource inputxsl=new XSLTInputSource(xslfilename);
        XObject mailURL = processor.createXString(mailUrl);
        processor.setStylesheetParam("mailurl",mailURL);
        XObject template = processor.createXString(templatevalue);
        processor.setStylesheetParam("templatevalue",template);
        processor.process(inputxml,inputxsl,new XSLTResultTarget(bStream));
```

XSLTProcessor,XSLTProcessorFactory,XSLTInputSource,XObject are showing error "cannot be resolved to a type"

i tried to import xslt jar files and park them in my eclipse class path...

i need guidance as to how to fix these errors as my application some .jsp files with the same error for xslt

Answer (score 0):

The classes seems to be part of Xalan. [Xalan Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan) or the [Apache Xalan Homepage](https://xalan.apache.org/).
But you should consider more up-to-date libraries due to existing vulnerabilities. E.g. [Saxon-HE](https://saxon.sourceforge.net/)